# Both SPA / SSR in sveltekit

Tags: sveltekit

I have a page `/categories`. In the `load` function from `/categories/+page.server.js` I load the categories through `data` from the DB as a JSON object and I display them in `/categories/+page.svelte` as a list. When the user clicks on a category, the system navigates to `/categories/1` where the user can view details of the category. The data for the category, are all included in the JSON I got from the list.

I want to be able to use the JSON data as input to the `/categories/1` page as an SPA to save on lag and network requests, but I also want a load function that would allow the loading of the category data (for SEO).

Allthough this should not be difficult to implement, I fail to understand how this can be accomblished.

Can somebody help me out with this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of loading your `categories` inside `+page.server.js` you could [load it in `+layout.server.js` to have them be available to all the child routes as well](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data).

**Example**

```js
// routes/categories/+layout.server.js
export function load() {
    return {
        categories: Array.from({ length: 10 }, (_, index) => ({
            id: index.toString(),
            text: Math.random().toString()
        }))
    };
}
```

```html
<!-- routes/categories/+page.svelte -->
<script>
    export let data;
</script>

{#each data.categories as category (category.id)}
    <a href="/categories/{category.id}">{category.text}</a>
{/each}

<style>
    a {
        display: block;
    }
</style>
```

```html
<!-- routes/categories/[id]/+page.svelte -->
<script>
    import { page } from '$app/stores';

    export let data;

    $: category = data.categories.find((c) => c.id === $page.params.id);
</script>

<h1>{category.text}</h1>
```