# Sveltekit call API from server and pass the data to the front-end

Tags: sveltekit

I'm learning Sveltekit and i've been stuck on passing data from backend to frontend. I have a 3rd party API that i want to call and send back the results that gives me the bearer needed for all the other API calls.
The problem is that the CORS policys of this server (that i have no control over) isn't configured well and i can't call the API from the browser.

So i wanted to call it from the backend and send the result to the front, what I did is a "+page.server.ts" file with the API call in the "load" function and puts the results in a store that i created in the stores.ts file :

```js
import { writable } from 'svelte/store';
export const token = writable('');
```

So in the front (+page.svelte) I just imported the token from the store and showed it :

```html
<script>
  import { token } from "../stores";
</script>
<h1>{$token}</h1>
```

And it works for a second before the token is overriden with an empty string and i don't get  why.

Do you have any idea of what could cause this ?

Feel free to ask for more informations if needed, because i'm lost right now

Comment: Maybe you could put the data loading in a [`layout.server.js`](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load#layout-data) file instead? That way you can use the data in all child pages as well without having to update a store manually. [Something like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74867419/both-spa-ssr-in-sveltekit) might give some inspiration.

Comment: @Tholle Thanks for your answer, i made something that works with the layout.server.ts as you said but my only problem now is that the load function of the layout.server.ts is triggered at every route change. I would like the exact same thing that is just called once in the app lifecycle.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot access a svelte store from within a server file.

Comment: That one should probably be a comment.

Answer (score -1):

To call a api from +page.server.js. Create a folder in your routes and add a +page.server.js file and add the following:

```js
/** @type {import('./$types').PageServerLoad} */

export async function load({ fetch }) {
    const res = await fetch('https://api.agify.io/?name=bella', {
        method: 'GET'
    });

    const data = await res.json();
    console.log(data);
    return {
        props: {
            data: data
        }
        
    };
}
```

Then create a +page.svelte with the following code:

```html
<script>
/** @type {import('./$types').PageData} */
export let data;
    console.log(data); 
    let name = data.props.data.name;
    let age = data.props.data.age;
</script>

<h1>
    {name} <!-- bella -->
    {age} <!-- the age -->
</h1>
```

SvelteKit docs have info that could be of use. [SvelteKit docs loading data](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs/load)